# Convergence of $\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}\dfrac{1}{n^{2+x}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Does $$\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}\dfrac{1}{n^{2+x}}, \ x \geq 0$$ converge uniformly on specified intervals?

I know that $\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}\dfrac{1}{n^{2}}$ converges when $|x|<1$. But what about $n^{2+x}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The given series is the  [Riemann zeta function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function)  and it's convergent if and only if

$$2+x>1\iff x>-1\iff x\in(-1,+\infty)$$

Comment: Congratulations for the $100$k's !

Answer (score 1):

Hint: If $x \geq 0$ then $2 + x \geq 2 \Rightarrow n^{2 + x} \geq n^2$ thus $$\frac{1}{n^{2 + x}} \leq \frac{1}{n^2}$$